# create a matrix with the same eigen valuess out of a larger one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I wanted to create a matrix ($n \times n$) with the same eigen value ($\lambda$). So I randomly generated an $n \times n$ matrix with the rank $n$. Then

$P^{-1}AP=\lambda I$

But I got A as just a $\lambda I$

$A = P\lambda I P^{-1} = PP^{-1}\lambda I = \lambda I$

Then I used a diagonal matrix $D$ instead of $\lambda I$ ($\lambda \ne 1$)

$D = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   \lambda &  &  & \\ 
   &  \ddots  &  & \\ 
   &  & \lambda  & \\
   &  &  & 1 \\ 
 \end{bmatrix}$

Then I got $A$, which has two eigenvalues: $\lambda$ with $n-1$ duplicity and 1 with one duplicity.

$A = PDP^{-1}$

Then I extracted $n-1 \times n-1$ matrix $A'$ (the first $n-1$ rows and columns of $A$). But $A'$ always has one eigenvalue which is different from $\lambda$. The other eigenvalues are $\lambda$ though. Is there a way to create a $n-1 \times n-1$ matrix that has the same eigenvalues out of $A$?

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly, but perhaps you can use identity matrices. Their eigenvalues will always be 1.

Comment: Thank you Shambhala,  I wanted to have a matrix with the duplicated $\lambda$. After reading your comment, I tried using a Jordan matrix instead of identity matrix and it worked.